# Converting a bar_index in the future to a date in Pinescript

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

In the example of TSLA the current bar_index is 3444 and I calculate a turning point at bar_index 3535 (trading days), how do I convert that 3535 into a date format dd/MM/YY to display in my table?

Tried str.format function having used str.tostring(3535) tried ChatGPT and after 1 hour it is still thinking about it!

Answer (score 0):

You can figure out the difference based on the timeframe and bar_index.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay = true)

b = bar_index
bNext = bar_index + 20
ms = timeframe.in_seconds()*1000
msToAdd = (bNext - b) * ms

futureTime = time + msToAdd

if barstate.islast
    label.new(bar_index,high,'Current Day: ' + str.format_time(time,'MM-dd-yy') + '\n20 Days From Now: ' + str.format_time(futureTime, 'MM-dd-yy'),color=color.lime)
```